# Select elements whose children don't contain specific elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select all divs on a page whose children **don't** contain an element with a specific class.

I can select elements whose descendants **do** contain the class with:

```
$('div').has('.myClass');
```

So I just want the inverse of this.

Comment: That sample there will find all the `<div>` elements with that class.  If you wanted to find all `<div>` elements that have at least one **child** element with that class, your example won't work.

Comment: @Pointy. Are you thinking of .hasClass()? .has() works for me

Comment: It will, has() will match any element that has a descendant that matches the selector. http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Comment: Yes sorry @pelms, @InfernalBadger - you're right. Must need more coffee.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd use ".filter()":

```
var theDivs = $('div').filter(function() {
  return $(this).find('.myclass').length === 0;
});
```

Comment: This works nicely, thanks. I was hoping there was a simple format possibly using 'not' but I guess not :¬)

Comment: You could try $('div:not(*>:has(.myClass))') which was Homer's original post. Seemed to work the same as Pointy's in jsfiddle.

Comment: @InfernalBadger can you help me understand what that "* >" does there?  How does that qualify an element?  Doesn't it just mean "child of any element"?

Comment: Not sure, just tried Homer's first post and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 5):

A simple `$("div:not(:has(.myClass))")` will do the job.

How it works internally in jQuery?

1) `$("div")` - gets all DIVs from the document.

2) `:not(:has(.myClass))` - These are two statements one nested in another. Now jQuery executes `:has(.myClass)` on resulted DIVs in above step and gets all DIVs with class name 'myClass'

3) `:not()` - This pseudo-selector method will be applied on All DIVs from Step 1 against the DIVs resulted from second statement to find DIVs without '.myClass'. This is possible by looping through all DIVs from Step 1 and comparing DIVs from second step.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div:not(:has(*>.myClass))');
```

Comment: yup the earlier version you posted works. this one doesn't. am on jquery 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').has(':not(.myClass)');
```

Comment: This is not really what the question is asking for.

Comment: I think this would select any element that has some class that isn't myClass (i.e. if an element has two classes, and one of them is myClass, it will still match, because it has a class that is not myClass).

Comment: Seems to work fine for me (http://jsfiddle.net/qAGNm/). Pointy's code works as well.

Comment: Wait - that will give you all `<div>` elements that have *any* descendant that doesn't have "myClass", right?

Comment: Although that's what I would expect to happen according to the jquery docs. When testing on jsfiddle it only appears to check direct children. Strange. Your code checks all descendants. It depends what @pelms wants I guess?

Comment: Unfortunately this selects all my divs since all contain some element that doesn't have class="myClass"